# Calling javascript function in android kitkat

Tags: javascript, android, android-4.4-kitkat

Since upgrading my nexus 4 to Android kitkat, my application stopped working. I was using javascript methods in webview but now my methods are not called. This is how i setup webview and load my javascripts:

```
 mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 JavaScriptInterface jsi = new JavaScriptInterface(mCtx);
 mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(jsi, ANDROID_BRIDGE);
 mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
 mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new OwnChromeClient());
 mWebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
 mWebview.loadUrl("about:blank"); //load dummy url to onPageFinished called in webViewClient
```

and my webClient:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(WebClient.class.getSimpleName(), description + " code "
                    + errorCode);
        }

        /**
         * Load javascript into webview
         */
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ECalcMarblesWrapper wrapper = new ECalcMarblesWrapper(mCtx);
            String javascripts = wrapper.getJavascripts();

            String content = String.format(jsHtmlContainer, javascripts,
                    jsHelpFunctions);

            view.loadUrl("javascript: " + content);
        }
    }
```

all loading methods are called but when i call any of javascript methods, this error is printed out to console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initForm is not defined

where initForm is my javascript method.

On api 18 application is doing just fine, i have javascript annotation in my methods

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for Kitkat version. I am facing the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If the target version of the application is set to 17 or higher you need to add annotation `@JavascriptInterface` above each method you want to export to the web view.

Comment: Thanks but i have that, on android api 18 application is doing just fine

Answer (score 0):

everything changes in Android kitkat for webview and javascript. you need to use `evaluateJavascript()`

check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html
and here: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String, android.webkit.ValueCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

Comment: Thanks mate, i know that i should call javascript function differently in kitkat but it seems that problem is in loading that js functions from file to webview